Radial Bar Charts with Kendo UI for Angular
Is it possible to use Kendo UI for Angular to plot Radial bar charts ?? I've seen pie charts and other types of charts that like gauge charts in their documentation... but nothing like radial bar charts like these ones: https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/radialbar-charts/ ... also attached an image to show what I'm trying to accomplish.

